# Query multiple models with class-based views

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I would like to solve the following situation.

I have a side panel containing information of the *active* user. For this an instance of UserInfo model needs to be passed to the views.

Additionally, I would like to pass a number of other model instances to the pages (eg. Purchases, Favourites, etc.).

I know this is pretty easy to do by overriding the get_context_data.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    kwargs['purchases'] = Purchases.objects.get(id=1)
    kwargs['favourites'] = Favourites.objects.get(id=1)
    .... etc
    return super(UploadFileView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

So my question is - what would be the best/most appropriate CBV to use for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't quite a `DetailView` as you have multiple objects, but it isn't a `ListView` either, nor does it look like a `FormView` or its children.

Since you gain nothing from those, a simple [TemplateView](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/class-based-views/base.html#templateview) is probably the way to go.

Comment: I agree. Thanks - I wanted to check my thinking as I am a new convert to CBVs so going through and refactoring my most used functions now and having to make some decisions.

Answer (score 2):

If you are querying the same UserInfo, Purchases, Favorites, etc in multiple views, create a Mixin that you can re-use.

```
class CommonUserInfoMixin (object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(OrgContextMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ... # Add more to context object
```

Then you can use this in your normal List, Detail, Update, etc CBV's

```
class ItemList(CommonUserInfoMixin, ListView):
    ....
```